# Failed to install gems via Bundler Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I try to push my Rails app to Heroku using git push heroku master command and I get this:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.1
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks’: No such file or directory
       Bundler Output: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks’: No such file or directory
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Why? I don't understand what happened. What should i do? if anyone understand this situation, please help me. Syota

**This is my Gemfile btw:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.4.1'

gem 'rails',  '5.0.3'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6' 
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'toastr-rails'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.5'
gem 'private_pub'
gem 'thin'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'payjp'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'listen', '~> 3.1.5'
gem 'nio4r'
gem 'pg', '0.20.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: You can follow this: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning Scroll down to the part where it says "Heroku".